# QOpenGLFunctions and PySide2

Tags: python, opengl, pyside2, pyopengl

How to use `QOpenGLFunctions` from `PySide2`?

The problem is with the `GLEnum`, which the API documentation mentions but doesn't tell from where one could take it.

For example, I would like to call `glGetString(),` I try:

```
from OpenGL import GL
from PySide2.QtGui import QOpenGLFunctions as GLF

GLF.glGetString(GL.GL_VERSION))
```

But it produces an error.

```
TypeError: descriptor 'glGetString' requires a 'PySide2.QtGui.QOpenGLFunctions' object but received a 'IntConstant'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a QOpenGLFunctions associated with a current QOpenGLContext, for example you can use the following code:

```
from OpenGL import GL
from PySide2 import QtGui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication()
    off_screen = QtGui.QOffscreenSurface()
    off_screen.create()
    if off_screen.isValid():
        context = QtGui.QOpenGLContext()
        if context.create():
            context.makeCurrent(off_screen)
            f = QtGui.QOpenGLFunctions(context)
            print(f.glGetString(GL.GL_VERSION))
```

Output:

```
3.0 Mesa 20.1.6
```